# Bash: `chmod a+x` Not Working When Run Inside Script

Tags: bash, chmod, permission-denied

I'm trying to simulate an update process via script.

I only care about the update script's exit code (`0` for success and any other value for failure).

I have created a simple script called `update.sh` to simulate an update:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1=true, 0=false
success=1

if [ $success -eq 1 ] ; then
    # Success.
    exit 0
else
    # Failure.
    exit 1
fi
```

To simulate a downloaded update, I have zipped `update.sh` into a file called `update-file.zip`.

My main script extracts `update-file.zip` and runs `update.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a fresh update folder.
rm -rfv /test/update && mkdir /test/update

# Simulate download by copying zip file to that folder.
cp -rf /update-file.zip /test/update/

cd /test/update
unzip -o update-file.zip

# Make the update script executable.
updateFile="/test/update/update.sh"
chmod a+x $updateFile

# Run the update.
/test/update/update.sh

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo "update failed"
else
    echo "update success"
fi

# Delete update folder.
rm -rfv /test/update
```

However, when I run my main script (even with `sudo`), I get the following error message:

```
/test/update/update.sh: Permission denied
```

Not even using a service (that uses `root` to do everything) helped, as I still got the same error message.

It seems that `chmod a+x` is not working when run inside scripts, because if I run `chmod a+x /test/update/update.sh` on the terminal, everything works fine.

Whenever `chmod a+x` is run from a script, I get "Permission denied" errors when trying to run the affected script.

What puzzles me is that when I run `ls -l /test/update/update.sh`, I get the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 131 Sep  9  2020 /test/update/update.sh
```

The output is the same regardless of whether `chmod a+x` is run from the terminal or a script.

I am on `Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)`.

Comment: Please try `cat -v /test/update/update.sh` from within your script before `/test/update/update.sh` and confirm it's actually your script contents?

Comment: Okay, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Also please check to be sure if your file doesn't have dos line endings. Does explicitly  running `bash /test/update/update.sh` work?

Comment: Will check your second comment as well and get back with results. :)

Comment: @KamilCuk I am a bit confused with the results. Adding `cat -v /test/update/update.sh` for some reason resolved the issue. I then removed this and tried `bash /test/update/update.sh`, which also resolved the issue.

I will choose to go with the `bash` option because it makes more sense, but I wonder why it worked despite `#!/bin/bash` already being present in `update.sh`.

Also, please add this as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: It could be you had some unprintable character on the `/test/update/update.sh` line in the script.

Comment: @KamilCuk Hmm, could be... Although I am using Notepad++ and have done `Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF)` for both files to make them compatible with Linux.

Comment: @KamilCuk Either way, please add `bash /test/update/update.sh` as an answer so I can accept it, as it has solved my problem. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may explicitly run the interpreter for the file:

```
bash /test/update/update.sh
```

There is no need to make the file executable then.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please use

> /bin/bash /test/update/update.sh

instead of

> /test/update/update.sh

in script.

Could you please provide output of below command as well once.

> ls -ld /test/update

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! This should work as well, but I have already accepted a previous answer earlier. Many thanks for sharing though! :)